# Pivot table indexing

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, pivot-table

I have two lists for columnheaders and rowheaders. I have created a pivot table on the basis of a data frame df so the code is:

```
df.pivot_table(value = "a", index = "b", columns = "c",aggfunc = "sum").reindex(index=rowheaders)
```

This works fine but I want to reindex the columns to columnheaders so I was trying:

```
df.pivot_table(value = "a", index = "b", columns = "c",aggfunc = "sum").reindex(index=rowheaders).reindex(index=columnheaders,axis=1)
```

but this doesn't work. Please help me out with a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For set columns use `axis=1`:

```
.reindex(columnheaders,axis=1)
```

Or `columns` parameter:

```
.reindex(columns=columnheaders)
```

If need both use:

```
.reindex(index=rowheaders, columns=columnheaders)
```